# Network.framework: nw_read_request_get_maximum_datagram_count

Tags: swift, server-side-swift, network.framework

I'm trying to get a UDP server functioning within Network.framework. However, whenever I managed to get my client and server connected, after some time I receive the error `nw_read_request_get_maximum_datagram_count`

I've tried looping with Timer and with DispatchQueue, but eventually the server or client crashes with the above error.

Client

```
import Foundation
import Network

class ExampleClient {
    lazy var connection: NWConnection = {
        let connection = NWConnection(
            to: .service(
                name: "Emma’s MacBook Pro",
                type: "_test._udp",
                domain: "local",
                interface: nil
            ),
            using: .udp
        )

        connection.stateUpdateHandler = { (newState) in
            switch newState {
            case .ready:
                self.loopForever()
            case .failed(let error):
                print("client failed with error: \(error)")
            default:
                break
            }
        }

        return connection

    }()

    func run() {
        connection.start(queue: DispatchQueue(label: "client"))

    }

    func loopForever() {
        while true {
            connection.send(content: "hello".data(using: .utf8), completion: .contentProcessed({ (error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("error while sending hello: \(error)")
                }

                self.connection.receiveMessage { (data, context, isComplete, error) in
                    return

                }

            }))

        }

    }

}

let client = ExampleClient()
client.run()

RunLoop.main.run()
```

Server

```
import Foundation
import Network

class ExampleServer {
    var connections = [NWConnection]()
    lazy var listener: NWListener = {
        let listener = try! NWListener(using: .udp)

        listener.service = NWListener.Service(type: "_test._udp")
        listener.serviceRegistrationUpdateHandler = { (serviceChange) in
            switch serviceChange {
            case .add(let endpoint):
                switch endpoint {
                case let .service(name, _, _, _):
                    print("listening as name \(name)")
                default:
                    break
                }
            default:
                break
            }

        }
        listener.newConnectionHandler = { (newConnection) in
            newConnection.start(queue: DispatchQueue(label: "new client"))
            self.connections.append(newConnection)

        }

        return listener

    }()

    func run() {
        self.listener.start(queue: DispatchQueue(label: "server"))

        while true {
            for connection in self.connections {
                connection.receiveMessage { (message, context, isComplete, error) in
                    connection.send(content: "world".data(using: .utf8), completion: .contentProcessed({ (error) in
                        if let error = error {
                            print("error while sending data: \(error)")

                        }

                    }))

                }

            }

        }

    }

}

let server = ExampleServer()
server.run()

RunLoop.main.run()
```

I'd like to maintain a constant connection between the server and client until the client or server manually disconnect.

Answer (score 2):

In the receiver, don't queue your receive handler inside your send's completion handler.

In the server, don't try to queue up an infinite number of receive handlers.  One at a time per connection is enough.

Comment: For anyone else stumbling upon this question like me, I want to clarify this point, and where I and - I think - OP got mixed up: receveMessage() does not block the thread waiting for a message, it simply *queues up* a handler, and then executes that closure code on another thread once the message is received. So indeed, that infinite loop is just infinitely queueing up message receiving handlers until it breaks. The better approach from what I can tell is to simply queue up the next message receive handler at the end of receiveMessage().